# How can I pull slideshow filenames from the database using jQuery?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I've have a jQuery plugin I'm using in my Drupal 7 site to make a fullpage background slider. I load it from a javascript file. How can I get the image names from Drupal's database instead of having to manually edit the list of images in the javascript file?

Here's the .js I load in my theme:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.BackgroundSlider = {
    attach: function(context, settings){
      $.backstretch([
            "/sites/default/files/styles/background_transition/public/ba5933c356c60f895785da952f8ad3e4_0.jpeg?itok=PjRiZj-V"
          , "/sites/default/files/styles/background_transition/public/8bad4c95b3776bed84222abe4c5288ba.jpeg?itok=cKq-2Dgj"
          , "/sites/default/files/styles/background_transition/public/78cefce14e9d9a613b0bc1950da662c6.jpeg?itok=4pAyvgsM"
          , "/sites/default/files/styles/background_transition/public/00336b1506db0487ea33af734abd3b16.jpeg?itok=QcS5dV2K"
      ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are they coming from different nodes with image field of 1, or they are coming from a single image field with unlimited values?

Comment: You do that in PHP, in a custom module for example. And then pass them over to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option - how about create a view to generate JSON for the image paths and then pull that into your JS?

The module "Views Datasource" can output your view as JSON.  You would need to create a view that pulls the images from the content type you are using and make sure that the image is rendered as a URL (rather than the actual image tag).

From there you could update your JS to pull the JSON from the view output.  Create a loop that sets a variable with the JSON data (as a comma separated list) and use that variable within your backstretch function.

I can't provide any code examples at this time, but hopefully that can get you started down a path.  Here is a stackoverflow article that provides examples on how to convert JSON to CSV and store that in a variable:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: Hey that's a good idea. Thanks I'll do some research on it